# Can't view Aarabic words in chrome/acrobat - ItextPDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, arabic

I have generated a pdf using `ItextPdf 5` in my java app. I am reading a template which has acro-form, I am updating the values of the editable fields (with `English` and `Arabic`) and regenerate a new pdf.

I can view Arabic in `Microsoft Edge` but the Arabic values are empty in `Chrome and`Adobe Reader`.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(templateSource);
PdfStamper stamper = mew PdfStamper(reader,new FileOutputStream(destinationPdf));
stamper.setFullCompression();
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);

Acrofieldsform form = stamper.getAcrofields();
form.setField("English_name","firstname");
form.setField("Arabic_name","جملة");

stamper.close();
reader.close();
```

Comment: This is related to Chrome and Adobe ... not Java?

Comment: There should be some support in API so that Arabic can be viewed properly. PDFBOX seems to work fine.

Comment: Have you tried it with iText 7 (+ optionally pdfCalligraph)? iText 5 is End Of Life.